# How to get rid of small circle graphic appearing at center of HTML-coded text in a customized Google Map?

Tags: html, graphics, geometry, maps, center

I'm an HTML novice, but here goes...

When zoomed way in, this is what I see at the center of various text line insertions:

[image: mystery circles]

You can see this live here: https://becketbroadband.org/fsa-map%2Fstatus

The apparently-responsible code looks like this:

```
addOverlay(Map, FSA05_Border, '49d834', 0.3, 'FSA-05', { lat: 42.305200, lng: -73.058500}, 'Service Available Now');
```

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You mean the tiny hollow circle in the second `a` in `Available` ?

Comment: Yes. Also in the capital A in the line above it.

Answer (score 0):

I see this in the code for `addOverlay`, at `fsa-map/status` on your site:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: labelPoint,
    map: BecketMap,
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, // anything, required
        fillOpacity: 0, // hide the symbol leaving just the label
    },
    label: {
        text: FSAlabel,
        color: &#x27;#000000&#x27;, // black
        fontSize: &#x27;20px&#x27;,
        fontWeight: &#x27;bold&#x27;,
    },
});
```

What happens if you don't supply an `icon` property at all?

Comment: Good thought. I also found an icon property reference a few lines below the first one. Taking either out reverses the order of the two lines of text in each region and adds a red location balloon at the center of the text, too. The balloon is on top of the FSA line and behind the other line of text for each region. Taking both icon property references out of the code causes two red location balloons to appear, one centered on each line of text and both layered behind the associated line of text. The icon property appears to suppress the balloon graphic from displaying.

Comment: Must be the opacity setting of zero. Sadly, it leaves the little circle behind. Odd, because the circle doesn't show when the balloon is present.

Comment: Oh, well. Turns out that the fillOpacity value doesn't have any effect. :(

Comment: My bad. Opacity setting isn't 1 to 10. It's 0 to 1. And it's meant to hide the circle, not the balloon (which is hidden by the icon property by default, apparently). Novice at the wheel. :P

Update: tried different values between 0 and 1. Makes no difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

The guy who wrote the original code came up with the answer. (He didn't have any ideas till I pointed out the icon property details addressed in this thread.)

The "fillOpacity" value addresses the inside of the circle. This new line of code addresses and hides the circle itself:

"strokeOpacity: 0,"

Thank you, AakashM, for getting me on the path to a solution! :) You da man!